# Using htaccess how to serve a subfolder as a WordPress page?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I'm trying to do is server a subfolder: /subsites/brighton/ when the url domain.com/pop-up-in-brighton/availability is visited (that url is/can be a WP page. Doesn't matter to me). The site is build on wordpress so that domain is itself the result of an apache rewrite.

I've looked at RewriteRule examples and tried to adapt them but failed miserably.  Can anyone help?

Whether it needs to be a rewriterule or maybe an alias?  It's shared hosting so only really have access to the htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^/pop-up-in-brighton/availability /subsites/brighton

    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think what you need to check is the virtual server directive, you can create a new website with it's own folder and IP.

```
<VirtualHost   10.20.30.1:80>
ServerAdmin    webmaster@host.example.com
DocumentRoot   /www/docs/host.example.com
ServerName     host.example.com
ErrorLog       logs/host.example.com-error_log
TransferLog    logs/host.example.com-access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

[Virtual server directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost)

also check this article about virtual hosts and .htaccess 
[.htacess and VH](http://blog.stefanxo.com/2013/09/move-your-htaccess-files-into-your-virtualhosts-file/)

Comment: Can this sort of thing not be done with htaccess?  I doubt I'll have access to apache config like that on shared hosting.  (ta btw!)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install wordpress in your sub directory `/subsites/brighton` and you can follow these instructions for using a sub directory.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Then you can point to that directory from `/pop-up-in-brighton/availability` using mod_rewrite in the .htaccess of you root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?yourdomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pop-up-in-brighton/availability [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /subsites/brigton [L]
```

See how that works. Replace yourdomain with your real domain.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion. Unfortunately the root directory is returning a 404 with this implemented (so the condition isn't being met presumably)

Comment: It shouldn't affect your root directory because if the request_uri condition is not met it will not process the rule. Do you have anything else in your .htaccess file. When testing that rule works for me.

Comment: I have the usual stuff WP puts into the htaccess file if you want to use permalinks.

http://pastebin.com/n6xbZrJ9